# Python + MySQL Не происходит заполнение БД

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, telegram-bot, insert

Попытался связать бота в телеграм с базой данных, но возникла проблема с её заполнением. Информация в БД не обновляется, скорее всего это связано с тем, что заполнение происходит с теле функции, поэтому это никак на неё не влияет. Как можно избежать данной проблемы? Ниже прилагаю отрывок кода:

```py
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

def get_name(message):
    add_newuser=("INSERT INTO user (id, nickname) VALUES (%(reg_id)s, %(nickname)s)")
    data_newuser={
      'reg_id' : message.from_user.id,
      'nickname' : message.text,
    }
    global cursor
    cursor.execute(add_newuser, data_newuser)
```

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Что то у меня туман в шаре магическом, никак не могу разобрать лог ошибок в вашем вопросе....

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков программа не выдаёт ошибок, но запрашивая полную базу данных у MySQL получаю такой ответ: Empty set (0.00 sec). Из этого я делаю вывод, что база данных не изменяется.
После рестарта программы бот меня забывает и просит повторно ввести свой nickname.

Comment: А вы их смотрите? ошибки? я в вашем коде не вижу чтоб вы запросили у MySQL коннектора список ошибок после выполнения запроса =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996401/error-handling-in-python-mysql

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков добавил отрывок из ссылки выше в свой код, на экране вывода ничего не получил. Попробовал посмотреть результат в случае, если оставить except: print("Error"), ничего не получил.

Comment: При необходимости могу приложить изменённый код.

Comment: Возможно, надо вызвать `conn.commit()` для сохранения изменений.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Вы оказались правы. Благодарю всех за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Решение: после выполнения всех запросов по изменению БД вызвать метод `commit()` у объекта соединения (не курсора). Если же Вы хотите менять БД сразу после любого запроса, то после создания соединения `conn` вызовите `conn.autocommit(True)`.